# NodeJs - how to populate the model view with data from another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model, controller

I am practicing Node by making a simple inventory app, in which I have 3 models: Item, Category and Manufacturer. What I want to do is, when displaying an item details, to include the Category and Manufacturer associated with that specific item, however it seems that I can not make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Item controller

```
const Item = require("../models/item");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Manufacturer = require("../models/manufacturer");

const async = require("async");

exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render("index", { title: "StrinGuist" });
};

//display list of all items
exports.item_list = function (req, res, next) {
  Item.find({}, "name description category in_stock price manufacturer")
    .populate("item")
    .exec(function (err, list_items) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("item_list", { title: "All items", item_list: list_items });
    });
};

//display detail page for a specific item
exports.item_detail = function (req, res, next) {
  async.parallel(
    {
      item: function (callback) {
        Item.findById(req.params.id)
          .populate("category")
          .populate("manufacturer")
          .exec(callback);
      },
    },
    function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (results.item == null) {
        // No results.
        const err = new Error("Item not found");
        err.status = 404;
        return next(err);
      }
      // Successful, so render.
      res.render("item_detail", {
        title: results.item.name,
        item: results.item,
      });
    }
  );
};
```

and here is the view (pug)

```
extends layout 

block content 
  h1 #{item.name}

  div(class='item-detail-content')
    p #[strong Price: $] #{item.price}
    p #[strong Description: ] #{item.description}
    p #[strong In stock: ] #{item.in_stock}
    p #[strong Manufacturer: ] #{item.manufacturer.name}
    p #[strong Category: ] #{item.category.name}
```

This throws me an error "Cannot read property 'name' of null", but I am not quite sure what is wrong. I tried also to declare Category and Manufacturer name as 'virtual', but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

For a ORM like mongoose when using mongodb, you can use the populate method with allows you do that.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html